# Python / Pandas - The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Tags: python, pandas, data-analysis

I have this two pandas objects (each of them is a a row taken out of a dataframe):

```
tg:

cnpj                               7350260000136
city_id                                        3
federation_unit_id                             8
primary_activity_id                            2
primary_activity_identifier           61.90-6-01
city_id                                        3
federation_unit_id                             8
CNAE                                  61.90-6-01
Name: tg, dtype: object


pred:

cnpj                       2178302000180
city_id                                3
federation_unit_id                     8
CNAE                          61.90-6-99
Name: pred, dtype: object
```

I'm trying to run the following if sentence:

```
x = 5
y = 1

if target.federation_unit_id == pred.federation_unit_id: x += y
```

The result here should be 6, however I'm getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/file.py", line 735, in <module>
target=index(pdsim,target,tgcsv='target_1.csv',predcsv='predictor_1.csv',pred_fine=pred_fine)
File "file.py", line 610, in similarity_index if target.federation_unit_id == pred.federation_unit_id: x += y
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 892, in __nonzero__
.format(self.__class__.__name__))
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Does anyone know how could I fix it?

Comment: try `print(type(target.federation_unit_id))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have a couple of issues.

1. It might have been a typo but your first series is 'tg' not 'target' not sure if that is some other series or dataframe
2. Even if that is a typo your first series has two elements called 'federation_unit_id' so tg.federation_unit_id gives two values which can't be compared to a single value.

If those weren't issues your code should work.